# How to make text appear in the middle of the screen?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've seen adventure maps that during the start they announce the name of the map with colourful text in the middle of the screen. How do they do this?

I've heard of it being called the `/title` command but I have no idea how to set it up. Even when I type `/title` in chat like this:

```
/title @a Squirrel Fun
```

It doesn't work. How to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

/title works differently to other commands in Minecraft because it uses raw JSON to print the message.
The way to do this is to write something like this in chat:

```
/title
```

^ That Declares that the title command is the command in use.

```
/title @a
```

^ That is a selector. There are different kinds of selectors:

@a = shows the title to everyone

@e = executes the command at all entities (Everything including mobs)

@r = A random player

@p = the nearest player

So now we have the selectors finished and we understand it we will add another segment of code:

```
/title @a title
```

The addon title confirms that the command in use is to broadcast a "title". Other uses are found by typeing /title .

```
/title @a title {"text":"Your Text"}
```

The command above will print "Your Text" without the quotations. The color will be white.

```
/title @a title {"text":"Your Text","color":"dark_red"}
```

So if we break off the curly bracket from the last sentance and add this  > ,"color":"dark_red"} < then that will print the 
default title ( Your Text ) but it will be dark red. If you change the color of "dark_red" ( not all colors are compatible ) then the text will change as well.

**For Skippers**

```
/title @a title {"text":"Your Text","color":"dark_red"}
```

change "Your Text" to the text you want ( enclosed in quotations ) and change "dark_red" to the color you want.

I have also enclosed a tellraw / title generator for those of you who don't want to learn this themselves.

Its found [here](http://minecraft.tools/en/title.php?title=%3Cspan%20style%3D%22color%3A%23AA0000%22%3EYour%20Text%3C%2Fspan%3E&subtitle=&actionbar_mode=0&fadein=1&fadeout=1&duration=5&selector=%40a)

Comment: Thanks. I'll probably just use the generator. Im not very good at commands

Answer (score 0):

```
/title @a title ***Your text here***
```

Put the text inside the asterisks.

I found this text out myself using [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/302267/how-to-make-text-appear-in-the-middle-of-the-screen) forum thing.